# I need help in creating a table in react with the help of bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

i actually want to create this table for my react project but i am facing issues in this project , can anybody help me out , i need to do it as a project for my department but i am not very familiar with bootstrap i have tried to do it by myself i have managed to make another tables but this particular table is giving me problems!

also can somebody tell how can i make the data to be dynamic like i need it to be fetched from a list also the table data like name , roll no and etc must be editable

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function ExamMarksTable() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([
        "To understand the Basics concepts of networking standards, protocols and technologies.",
        "To learn the different signal transmission, multiplexing techniques.",
        "To learn the role of protocols at various layers in the protocol stacks",
        "To learn the different IEEE standards.",
    ]);

    const [editIndex, setEditIndex] = useState(null);
    const [editedData, setEditedData] = useState([...data]);

    const handleEdit = (index) => {
        setEditIndex(index);
        setEditedData([...data]); // Reset edited data
    };

    const handleInputChange = (event, index) => {
        const newData = [...editedData];
        newData[index] = event.target.value;
        setEditedData(newData);
    };

    const handleSave = (index) => {
        setEditIndex(null);
        setData([...editedData]); // Save edited data
    };

    return (
        <div className="container-fluid w-100 border border-danger border-3 mt-4 text-dark">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col">
                    <div className="row text-dark no-wrap fs-4 d-flex justify-content-center font-weight-bold">
                        <div className="col-1 fs-4 fw-bold border border-2 px-5 py-5">Sr.No</div>
                        <div className="col-1 fs-4 fw-bold border border-2 px-5 py-5">Roll No.</div>
                        <div className="col-1 fs-4 fw-bold border border-2 px-5 py-5">Prn No.</div>
                        <div className="col-3 fs-4 fw-bold border border-2 px-5 py-5">Student Name</div>
                        <div className="col-6 fs-4 fw-bold border border-2 px-2 py-2">
                        <div className="col-12 fs-4 fw-bold px-2 py-2">CO Attainment from University Exam</div>
                        <div className="col-12 fs-4 fw-bold px-2 py-2 d-flex">
                        <div className="fs-4 fw-bold border border-2 px-2 py-2">ESE</div>
                        <div className="fs-4 fw-bold border border-2 px-2 py-2">Mid Sem</div>
                        <div className="fs-4 fw-bold border border-2 px-2 py-2">PR/OR</div>
                        <div className="fs-4 fw-bold border border-2 px-2 py-2">Term Work</div>
                        <div className="fs-4 fw-bold border border-2 px-2 py-2">Total</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-12 fs-4 fw-bold px-2 py-2 d-flex">
                        <div className="fs-4 fw-bold border border-2 px-2 py-2">70</div>
                        <div className="fs-4 fw-bold border border-2 px-2 py-2">30</div>
                        <div className="fs-4 fw-bold border border-2 px-2 py-2">25</div>
                        <div className="fs-4 fw-bold border border-2 px-2 py-2">25</div>
                        <div className="fs-4 fw-bold border border-2 px-2 py-2">150</div>

                        </div>


                        </div>

                    </div>
                    {data.map((item, index) => (
                        <div className="row align-items-center hover-overlay" key={index}>
                            <div className="col-6 border border-2 px-2 py-3 fs-4 w-25 d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-start hover-shadow">
                                <span>{`${index + 1}`}</span>
                                <div>
                                    {editIndex === index ? (
                                        <button className="btn btn-success ms-2" onClick={() => handleSave(index)}>Save</button>
                                    ) : (
                                        <button className="btn btn-light border border-3 ms-3" onClick={() => handleEdit(index)}>Edit</button>
                                    )}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {editIndex === index ? (
                                <div className="col-5 border border-2 fs-4 px-2 py-3 w-75">
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control fs-5" value={editedData[index]} onChange={(event) => handleInputChange(event, index)} />
                                </div>
                            ) : (
                                <div className="col-5  border border-top-0 border-2 fs-5 px-2 w-75 " style={{ paddingTop: "23px", paddingBottom: "20px", display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>{item}</div>
                            )}
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ExamMarksTable;
```